# CSS Hide object Scroll Percentage

Tags: css, scroll, hide, percentage

Does anyone know how to hide an object depending on how much the user has scrolled down the page?

I have some floating social buttons on my website and I want them to hide when the scroll reaches the footer (the very bottom) and then appear once they scroll back up.

Comment: please post a jsfiddle of your code.

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't be done with CSS alone, you have to use javascript to keep track of how much the user has scrolled.

If you can use jQuery, you have to do something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        $("#social").hide();
    } else {
        $("#social").show();
    }
});
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akdyqhrm/1/). However, this is just a guess of what you need as you didn't provide the proper code. If you need a javascript only solution (without jQuery) let me know.